# Change Laptop Wireless Card?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-card

I have just bought a new Samsung RV511 Laptop (the i5 Version).

Anyway it comes installed with a Broadcom Wifi Card, I have a Super Atheros Mini Wifi Card that I would like to swap for the Broadcom one. I use Atheros for security auditing purposes in Linux that the Broadcom one is not good for.

Trouble is I have never got to the barebones of a laptop, although I am a Custom PC Builder, laptops i generally have no concern for.

Take a look at this picture, I took one back panel off to reveal some of the components:

[image]

I believe the Wireless Card is where I marked the arrow pointing too. That little white square thing appears to be a sticker of the Wifi card, it says WLAN.

How can I access it to swap it with my Atheros one. Do I need to remove all the outermost screws? There are screws located to the right of where I scribbled in Yellow and next to the HDD, do I just remove those?

I dont want to destroy the machine, only just got it today.

Appreciate some help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to remove more screws. Most wireless cards use an internal connector that looks a lot like a memory slot. You'll need to keep removing screws (carefully) until you get to the device that should look nearly exactly like your Atheros card.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful when removing parts from the back like that. I've taken apart my laptop a couple times and a method I use to organize my pieces is as follows:

Make sure you have a large space (like a table) around
Every time you take off a piece (carefully), put the piece furthest from you and put the screws in the holes in the plastic/metal piece.
Keep doing this in sequential order
When you reach your wireless card, remove it and put your new one it. Pray to Science that it isn't attached using specific flex cable.
Once its switched, put the pieces back in, starting from the piece closest to you.

This may seem easy and babyish but you miss one small black piece and you're TOAST. Make sure you put them back in the same order you took them off.

Good luck with this, happy hacking!